# UIImageView inheritance for round corners

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

I have lots of places where I use profile images with rounded corners. And instead of writing each time

```
 profileImageView.layer.cornerRadius = profileImageView.frame.size.width / 2;
```

I have decided to create my own class that would inherit UIImageView. 
And add corners in init function

```
class UISlProfileImageView: UIImageView {
    override init(image: UIImage?){
        super.init(image:image)
        roundCorner()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
}

extension UISlProfileImageView{
    func roundCorner(){
        self.layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.size.width / 8;
        self.clipsToBounds = true
    }
}
```

The problem is that after I have changed in Storyboard the appropriate picture to UISlProfileImageView, round coreners diappeared. Could you advice me please, what I am doing wrong. I have put a break point in the init of my new class and strangely it didn't stop there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should override the method layoutSubviews() and call roundCorner() inside that method. Such as

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()

    roundCorner()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have an option to round each `UIImageView`, you can copy this code into your project without forgetting to check `clip to bounds` and set its value to `true`

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable
extension UIImageView
{
    private struct AssociatedKey
    {
        static var rounded = "UIImageView.rounded"
    }

    @IBInspectable var rounded: Bool
    {
        get
        {
            if let rounded = objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &AssociatedKey.rounded) as? Bool
            {
                return rounded
            }
            else
            {
                return false
            }
        }
        set
        {
            objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &AssociatedKey.rounded, newValue, .OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC)
            layer.cornerRadius = CGFloat(newValue ? 1.0 : 0.0)*min(bounds.width, bounds.height)/2
        }
    }
}
```

[image: storyboard screenshot]